# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, ppa

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu yakkety Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/yakkety/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: And what are you doing? What command did you run? What did you try to solve it? Obviously you searched Google for the error before coming here, so what did that tell you? Please [edit] your question and explain what you were doing and what you've tried.

Comment: apt has very bad error messages. Has not Release file could also mean you do have a typo in your address or no internet connection at all. You should check if http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu displays the files in a browser.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

- Open `Software & Updates`, `Other Software` tab.
- find the PPA definition that contains "gnome-terminator"
- select it and click `Edit`
- change the `Distribution` field from yakkety to xenial
- save the changes
- update the software database when prompted
- problem solved

Source: http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: for me it was 'bionic' and I changed to xenial, fixed the issue, but I don't understand why it doesn't have the bionic dist?

Comment: @sangress If you look at `http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/` you'll see that there's not a bionic distribution directory for this software.

Comment: @sangress it was the exact same for me.

Comment: This should be accepted as the correct answer

Comment: Just test it with Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: is it ok use this for focal release too?

Comment: @ZahraShahrouzi Yes. Just change focal to xenial.

Comment: I found out we don't even need to add a PPA in the latest Ubuntu 20.04; just run `sudo apt install terminator`

Comment: Thank you so much!! Still belive this kind of thing shouldn't be this hard to solve.