# The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt, gnome, updates, kubuntu, ppa

I was trying to get a repository to install Ukuu for the new Kernel and I noticed this message:

The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file. I saw another question with the same topic but it was for Ubuntu and I run Kubuntu so I don't really know how to open "Software and updates".

[The question I'm talking about](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940658/the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-gnome-terminator-ppa-ubuntu-yakkety-rel)

Could anyone please tell me how to solve that error in Kubuntu? I am a newbie in Linux so help is much appreciated.

Comment: It is the same question and answer: The PPA you refer to does not support focal, [see here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu/dists/).

Comment: yes I understand, but it says that I have to open "Software & Updates" to change the distribution but I can't find that part in Kubuntu.

Comment: You open "Software And Updates" in kde using the command `software-properties-kde`. Remember to use `sudo`.